# Visualsearch.js in Drupal module page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, drupal-6

I'm having trouble getting the [visualsearch.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/visualsearch/) control up and running on my Drupal module page.  I'm using the exact same javascript as in the demo.html script block (you can find it in download zip package or by viewing the source code of the demo of their site), which I copied and pasted into a separate javascript file. I've also loaded all the css and javascript dependencies in my Drupal module, following the order defined in demo.html.

*Drupal Code*

```
<?php

    function mymodule_menu() {
        $items = array();

        $items['mymodule'] = array(
            'title' => 'MyModule',
            'page callback' => 'mymodule_main',
            'access callback' => TRUE,
            'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM
        );

        return $items;
    }

    function mymodule_main() {

        drupal_add_css(absolute paths of all css dependencies);
        drupal_add_js(absolute paths of all javascript dependencies (in order), followed by the standalone javascript file that contains the code extracted from the demo.html script block);

        return "
            <div id=\"VS\" class=\"container\">
                <div id=\"searchbox\"></div>
                <div id=\"feedback\"></div>
            </div>";
    }
```

I ran this exact same setup in a pure html/javascript environment and everything worked fine.  That is, I made an html page that loaded the dependencies and contained the html as shown above. Then, I had a separate script containing the code extracted from the demo.html script block.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this problem.

In the demo implementation of visualsearch, the container references the id attribute of the visualsearch div. In order for visualsearch to work in Drupal, the container must reference the **class** attribute instead.

*Drupal module*

```
...
return "<div id=\"searchbox\" class=\"searchbox\"></div>";
```

*Javascript*

```
window.VisualSearch = VS.init({
    container : $('.searchbox'),
    ....
```